# How can I phase-shift variables to offset plots?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm plotting an EMA function but want to offset it, say, by 3 bars.

I know I can use the history referncing operator to phase shift a plot forward in time, or to use "offset" in the "plot" function, but how do I phase shift "emaShort" back in time to the left, without using "offset" in "plot" ("plot" isn't itself a variable so I wouldn't be able to use it to define a strategy?). Here is my code so far:

```
// Set the input variables
emaShortLength = input.int(8, title="Short EMA Length")

// Calculate the EMAs
emaShort = ta.ema(close, emaShortLength)

// Calculate the offset EMAs
leadingema = ta.ema(close[3]+lagShort[3], emaShortLength)

// Plot the EMAs and the offset EMAs
plot(zlemaShort, color=color.blue, title="Short EMA", offset=-3)
plot(zlemaShort, color=color.green, title="zlema Short")
plot(leadingema, color= color.white, title="Leading EMA")
```

Comment: What exactly do you need to use offset here? Do you want to use it in a condition?

Comment: @vitruvius, yes I would like to test offset EMAs in crossover conditions

Comment: What's the issue with using the history reference operator then?

Comment: It is not clear to me that what the problem is and what your intentions are.

Comment: Sorry, using the history referencing operator enables me to plot historical values now, phase-shifting the EMA to the right on a chart. The problem is how do I phase-shift the EMA values to the left (without using 'offset' in 'plot')?